# Why is my script not letting my bot add reactions to the embed message it is sending? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

---

I am a big novice with JavaScript coding so if you can make this a pre simple explanation that'd be MUCH appreciated.

So basically I have made this small script in order to send a poll to another channel using the arguments I have made the user put in and then format it and send it as an embedded message

The script is sending the whole thing formated however the final step of not adding the reactions is the issue.
(they are custom reactions which I have already defined *you'll see below*)

```
if (args.length >= 1) {
    message.delete().then(() => {
      const pollEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor('#ABDFF2')
      .setTitle("** " + pollArgs[0] + " **")
      .setDescription(pollArgs[1])
      .addField('*Click on the reactions below to cast your opinion on this poll!*', 'If you would like to start your own poll: !help in <#726235250136580106>')
      .setTimestamp()
      .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL)
      .setFooter(message.author.tag + " | Peace Keeper", message.author.displayAvatarURL)
      let yes = message.guild.emojis.find('name', "yes")
      let no = message.guild.emojis.find('name', "no")
      suggestionschannel.send(pollEmbed).then(message.react(yes, no));
```

---

In case you need to see the full code here it is:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  const suggestionschannel = message.guild.channels.find("name", "suggestions");
  let pollArgs = args.slice(0).join(" ").split('|');

  if (args.length >= 1) {
    message.delete().then(() => {
      const pollEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor('#ABDFF2')
      .setTitle("** " + pollArgs[0] + " **")
      .setDescription(pollArgs[1])
      .addField('*Click on the reactions below to cast your opinion on this poll!*', 'If you would like to start your own poll: !help in <#726235250136580106>')
      .setTimestamp()
      .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL)
      .setFooter(message.author.tag + " | Peace Keeper", message.author.displayAvatarURL)
      let yes = message.guild.emojis.find('name', "yes")
      let no = message.guild.emojis.find('name', "no")
      suggestionschannel.send(pollEmbed).then(message.react(yes, no));
    })
  } else {
    message.delete().catch();
    const pollErrEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor('FF6961')
      .setTitle("**error!**")
      .addField("use the correct format: !polls-start <title> | <message>", "If you need help do: `!polls-help`.")
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter(message.author.tag + " | Peace Keeper", message.author.displayAvatarURL)
      message.reply(pollErrEmbed).then(msg => msg.delete(10000));
  }
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "polls-start"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems good only one tiny edit!

Instead of

`suggestionschannel.send(pollEmbed).then(message.react(yes, no));`

You would need to use

```js
suggestionschannel.send(pollEmbed).then(message => {
message.react(yes);
message.react(no);
});
```

Also remember about [Updating Discord.js to v12](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html), as soon v11 support is going to end!